# Dual stack Apache

Tags: apache2, ipv6

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server with a number of IPv4 addresses and a /64 of IPv6 addresses. I have it responding to its IPv6 addresses with ping6. I'd like the domains hosted on the server to go dual-stack, so IPv6-enabled visitors will be able to access its sites over IPv6, and everyone else will use IPv4.

Here's the relevant parts of my Apache config as it stands now:

**ports.conf:**

```
NameVirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80
Listen 199.192.201.82:80
Listen [2607:ff50:0:21::2]:80
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80>
    ServerName  cdc.nexussl.net

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80>
    ServerName  ipv6.nexussl.net

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80>
    ServerName  dual.nexussl.net

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

[cdc.nexussl.net](http://cdc.nexussl.net/) has an A record pointing to 199.192.201.82, [ipv6.nexussl.net](http://ipv6.nexussl.net/) has a AAAA record pointing to 2607:ff50:0:21::2, and [dual.nexussl.net](http://dual.nexussl.net/) has both an A and a AAAA record.

With that setup, IPv4 works fine (They should all display a "You look lost" page), but visiting ipv6.nexussl.net or dual.nexussl.net from an IPv6-capable machine returns

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at ipv6.nexussl.net Port 80
```

dual.nexussl.net works correctly on an IPv4-only connection. Ultimately, I'd like all sites to be set up in DNS like dual.nexussl.net, with both A and AAAA records.

In Apache's config, I can't just use `Listen 80`, because other applications on that server use port 80 on other IPs. Apache should only use 199.192.201.82 as far as IPv4 goes.

As far as IPv6, should I give each site its own IPv6 address, and they'll just share one IPv4? I feel like that could get messy listing an IPv6 address in `ports.conf` for every site. Even if I'm having them all share an IPv6 address, how do I get Apache to serve sites correctly over IPv6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your AAAA records have to point to your IPv6 address, not to 199.192.201.82 (which is technically impossible, so I wouldn't be surprised that that's a typo).

Here is a correct config:

**ports.conf:**

```
Listen 199.192.201.82:80
NameVirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80

Listen [2607:ff50:0:21::2]:80
NameVirtualHost [2607:ff50:0:21::2]:80
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80>
    ServerName  cdc.nexussl.net

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost [2607:ff50:0:21::2]:80>
    ServerName  ipv6.nexussl.net

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80 [2607:ff50:0:21::2]:80>
    ServerName  dual.nexussl.net

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog  /var/www/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You're right, that was a typo. Your solution works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: was having a major headache with TLS on our server not being served for ipv6 which was recently rolled out in my area.  this really helped me out.